# DDEV ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'db'

Tags: mysql, docker, ddev

I accidentally deleted my default `db` database without re-creating it, but had exit the container and now I can't `ddev ssh` into the project or even connect to mysql.

> Project is not currently running. Try 'ddev start'.

Even though the containers are already up and running.

So did `docker exec -it ddev-project-db bash`, but then upon `mysql -u root -p` it keeps prompting with:

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'db'

How can I create the `db` again?

When I try to re-create the whole project, the web container persistently fails with:

> Container ddev-project-web  Started
> Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: db container failed: log=, err=health check timed out after 2m0s: labels map[com.ddev.site-name:project com.docker.compose.service:db] timed out without becoming healthy, status=
> Container ddev-router  Started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily fix this with
`ddev delete --omit-snapshot -y && ddev start`

which will destroy your broken database environment, create a new one, and start up the project. Then you can import your database again with `ddev import-db` or restore a snapshot with `ddev snapshot restore`